# TypeError at /candidate/1/

Tags: django, django-models

I used positional parameters and it is showing that

> Position is not Iterable

as Position is Object

The views.py file has an problem as it is showing error when I use this Positional parameter

views.py

```
def candidate_view(request,pos):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Position,pk=pos)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("You are in ")
        return HttpResponse("Voted")
    else:
        return render(request, 'poll/candidate.html', {'obj': obj})
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name="home"),
    path('register',views.register,name="register"),
    path('login',views.view_login,name="view_login"),
    path('logout',views.view_logout,name="view_logout"),
    path('candidate/<int:pos>/',views.candidate_view,name="candidate_view"),
    path('positions',views.position_view,name="position_view"),
    path('result',views.result,name="result"),
]
```

Position.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Positions{% endblock %}
{%block body%}
 <h2>Available Position For Vote</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for i in obj %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'candidate_view' i.id%}">{{i.title}}</a></li>
    {% empty %}
      <p>No Positions Available</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Models.py

```
class Position(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#This is model of candidate
class Candidate(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pos = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} -- {}".format(self.full_name,self.pos.title)
```

error:

```
TypeError at /candidate/1/
'Position' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/candidate/1/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'Position' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\Users\Anil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py, line 167, in render
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Anil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Anil\\PycharmProjects\\E_Voting\\ovs',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 01 Jun 2021 11:18:01 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below change

```
def candidate_view(request,pos):
        obj = Position.objects.filter(pk=pos)
        if request.method == "POST":
            print("You are in ")
            return HttpResponse("Voted")
        else:
            return render(request, 'poll/candidate.html', {'obj': obj})
```

Comment: which template??

Comment: in Position.html

Comment: No it is not showing error because In position template I m just Iterating over Position instance using For loop in the template. The problem is in view.py here obj = get_object_or_404(Position,pk=pos) here the error is arising\??

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you are building?

Comment: A simple Online Voting System project for mini project but I stuck here ...

Comment: Can you just tell me that what is the problem ??

Comment: actually, I am not understood your requirement otherwise this issue is not a big deal

Comment: The main purpose is that when I want to click on the first link let say president then it would return the corresponding candidates to the president and so on .....

Comment: Now it is working and showing en error but now not showing the candidate's name..